# What other public firmware/reverse engineered alternatives are available to replace stock firmware?

Tags: firmware

Recently I have taken an interested in learning about Linux and the Unix family of operating systems.

In my quest to do so I found that my simple home router contained hardware capable of much more than I thought. It was a fully fledged computer running Linux!

I was able to load both [Openwrt](https://openwrt.org/) and then DD-wrt allowing experimentation with a mini Linux computer.

Im also aware that there are many other possiblities for router/modem firmware:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wireless_router_firmware_projects

Other projects that give this possibility are:

1. Cyanogenmod (plus many more) for many Android based mobiles
2. FreemyiPod for Apple iPods
3. Rockbox for other Mp3 players including iPods

---

What other popular projects are available that provide customized firmware or an alternative to proprietary software that can be loaded on to a device?

Is anyone able to provide a link to any lists of such projects?

Comment: This question does not really belong here, you should probably look on the superuser stack overflow, there are already topics about like this one : http://superuser.com/questions/316177/openwrt-vs-ddwrt?rq=1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, would be more relevant on the superuser stack exchange

Comment: Basically I'm looking for other devices I can load reverse engineered/alternative firmware on. I figured the reverse engineering community would have a good idea of current projects. If it is off topic is there a way I can move it?

Comment: @suit There's the Canon Hack Development Kit.